# How does one use enable_if for mutually exclusive non-member function templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I'm trying to write non-member operator function templates like:

```
#include <utility>

template < typename T, unsigned L >
class MyType;

template < typename T, typename U, unsigned L >
auto  operator ==( MyType<T,L> const &l, MyType<U,L> const &r )
 -> decltype( std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>() )
{ /*...*/ }
```

But when I try to handle when `l` and `r` have different lengths:

```
template < typename T, unsigned Lt, typename U, unsigned Lu, class Enable = typename std::enable_if<(Lt < Lu)>::type >
auto  operator ==( MyType<T,Lt> const &l, MyType<U,Lu> const &r )
 -> decltype( std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>() )
{ /*...*/ }

template < typename T, unsigned Lt, typename U, unsigned Lu, class Enable = typename std::enable_if<(Lt > Lu)>::type >
auto  operator ==( MyType<T,Lt> const &l, MyType<U,Lu> const &r )
 -> decltype( std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>() )
{ /*...*/ }
```

I get ambiguity errors.  I tried something like:

```
template < typename T, unsigned Lt, typename U, unsigned Lu, bool B = (Lt < Lu), class Enable = typename std::enable_if<B>::type >
auto  operator ==( MyType<T,Lt> const &l, MyType<U,Lu> const &r )
 -> decltype( std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>() )
{ /*...*/ }

template < typename T, unsigned Lt, typename U, unsigned Lu, bool B = (Lt > Lu), class Enable = typename std::enable_if<B>::type >
auto  operator ==( MyType<T,Lt> const &l, MyType<U,Lu> const &r )
 -> decltype( std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>() )
{ /*...*/ }
```

which I've read (here on S.O.) to solve problems like this for member function templates.  (Sometimes, the respondents changed a member function to a member function template to enable this.)  But the errors don't change for me.  Do I have to switch to putting `enable_if` into the return type?

Oh, the return type expression is supposed to exclude this operator when the two element types can't be compared.  Will it actually work?  Is it compatible with putting the `enable_if` around there too?

Comment: What exactly is the ambiguity error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interestingly, a [certain fellow here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) wrote a blogpost just a short time ago, showing a nice C++11-style SFINAE technique that easily allows overloaded functions. The technique and explanation are provided [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150726012736/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/almost-static-if/).

In short, your code fails because both templates, when parsed the first time and when non-dependant declarations are resolved, are *exactly* the same, type-wise. As with default function arguments, default template arguments are only substituted when the function is actually called. This is what both templates look like to the compiler at the point of declaration:

```
template<class T, unsigned Lt, class U, unsigned Lu, class Enable>
auto operator==(MyType<T,Lt> const& l, MyType<U,Lu> const& r);
```

The following code should achieve what you want:

```
namespace detail{
enum class enabler{};
}

template<bool B, class T = detail::enabler>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;

template < typename T, unsigned Lt, typename U, unsigned Lu, EnableIf<(Lt < Lu)>...>
auto  operator ==( MyType<T,Lt> const &l, MyType<U,Lu> const &r )
 -> decltype( std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>() )
{ /*...*/ }

template < typename T, unsigned Lt, typename U, unsigned Lu, EnableIf<(Lt > Lu)>...>
auto  operator ==( MyType<T,Lt> const &l, MyType<U,Lu> const &r )
 -> decltype( std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>() )
{ /*...*/ }
```

One question remains, however... what should happen if `Lt == Lu`? In that case, neither overload is viable.

Comment: Wow! My mind got blown. I had thought about the multi-condition (easy enough with variadic), but... combining so many technics and managing to hit such a syntactical sweet spot. Amazing. Thanks for sharing the article.

Comment: The version of `operator ==` in the first block covers the case when the class template's second parameters are equal.  The two versions I'm asking about are in addition to the first version, and are not replacing it.

Comment: That is a *very* interesting article.  For my code, I used `typename std::enable_if<(Lt < Lu)>::type...` as the final template parameter.  My compiler, GCC-4.7 (32-bit PowerPC, from MacPorts), accepted that parameter, even though it's technically `void...` (an incomplete type) and the article said that `void` couldn't be used!  I was planning to use `std::nullptr_t` or `int` since I didn't want to add a throwaway type to library code (but, never mind).

Comment: @CTMacUser yeah, there's no big problem with using `int` or `std::nullptr_t`. I just like to be extra cautious :)