# enable_if seems to work outside a class but not inside

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

Here is my somewhat odd code:

```
template <typename T&>
class A {  
public:  
  void b(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>;::type o) {}  
  void b(typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>;::type o) {}  
};  

template <typename T>  
void b(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type o) {}  
template <typename T>  
void b(typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type o) {}
```

If I `ifdef` out the method `b` and call `b<int *>(pi`) where `pi` is `int *`, everything compiles.

If I `ifdef` out the function `b` (outside class) and call `A<int *> a; a.b(pi)`, I get the following error:

> `error: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if<false, int *>'`

Why the inconsistency and how can I fix the problem so that I can use the methods in A?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is, that SFINAE only works during overload resolution and only if the function *itself* is a template. In your method case, the whole *class* is a template, meaning that there is no *substitution* of the template parameter (remember: SFINAE == "**Substitution** Failure Is Not An Error").

At the point of instantiation, the method signatures look like this (nevermind the call to them):

```
void A<int*>::b(std::enable_if<false, int*>::type o) // error
void A<int*>::b(std::enable_if<true, int*>::type o)
```

To fix this, make the methods templates too:

```
template<class T>
class A{
public:
  template<class U>
  void b(U o, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<U>::value>::type* = 0){}
  // same for the other version
};
```

On a side note, letting the template argument get deduced is the better way to use SFINAE, so you should modify the free functions to look like this:

```
template<class T>
void b(T o, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type* = 0){}
// same for the other version
```

In C++11, you can even use the template parameters for SFINAE:

```
template<class T, EnableIf<std::is_pointer<T>> = {}>
void b(T o);
```

Utilizing an alias from the blog entry linked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862423/500104):

```
namespace detail{ enum class enabler{}; }

template<class Cond, class T = detail::enabler>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<C::value, T>::type;
```

Comment: It would be good to explain how to "transform" the methods by adding dummy template arguments to re-activate SFINAE on them.

Answer (score 4):

For the explanation, see Xeo's answer.

For the work-around: just add a dummy template parameter to the method

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class A {  
public:
  template <typename U = T>
  void b(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<U>::value, U>::type o);

  template <typename U = T>
  void b(typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<U>::value, U>::type o);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
void A<T>::b(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<U>::value, U>::type o) {}  

template <typename T>  
template <typename U>
void A<T>::b(typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<U>::value, U>::type o) {} 


int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.b(0);
}
```

[Live Demo Here](http://ideone.com/tRxrR).

Comment: This does not help, the method signature is fixed, the substitution happens at the instantiation point of `A`. Also, the free functions don't look quite right. :P

Comment: @Xeo: those were not intended to be free-functions but definitions of the methods (to illustrate that the default should not be repeated). Anyway I patched it up.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using SFINAE correctly because the compiler can't deduce the argument for `enable_if<...>::type` and probably that's why it fails.

Correct declarations of free-standing functions would be:

```
template <typename T>  
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, void>::type b(T o);

template <typename T>  
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, void>::type b(T o);
```

In this particular case plain function overloading can be used as well:

```
template <typename T>  
void b(T);

template <typename T>  
void b(T*);
```

Comment: What? Using `enable_if` as the OP does is perfectly fine, if the member methods themselves were templates.