# SFINAE Based on Class Member Existence/Absence

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I have a basic understanding of SFINAE, e.g. how `enable_if` works. I recently came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13787502/573432), and I've spent over an hour trying to understand how it actually works to no avail.

The goal of this code is to overload a function based on whether a class has a specific member in it. Here's the copied code, it uses C++11:

```
template <typename T> struct Model
{
    vector<T> vertices;

    void transform( Matrix m )
    {
        for(auto &&vertex : vertices)
        {
          vertex.pos = m * vertex.pos;
          modifyNormal(vertex, m, special_());
        }
    }

private:

    struct general_ {};
    struct special_ : general_ {};
    template<typename> struct int_ { typedef int type; };

    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs,
             typename int_<decltype(Lhs::normal)>::type = 0>
    void modifyNormal(Lhs &&lhs, Rhs &&rhs, special_) {
       lhs.normal = rhs * lhs.normal;
    }

    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    void modifyNormal(Lhs &&lhs, Rhs &&rhs, general_) {
       // do nothing
    }
};
```

For the life of me, I can't wrap my head around how this mechanism works. Specifically, what does `typename int_<decltype(Lhs::normal)>::type = 0` help us do, and why do we need an extra type (`special_`/`general_`) in this method.

Comment: To me it looks that the example is not valid; the forwarding reference will not fire `decltype(Lhs::normal)` if `Lhs` is an lvalue. It should be `decltype(std::declval<Lhs>().normal)`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki The example runs, I tested it.

Comment: It compiles, but did you check if it gives a correct result?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, it runs and produces results as expected.

Comment: @Phonon mind posting your working version in http://ideone.com/? because for me it doesn't give the correct result if called with a lvalue.

Comment: @Phonon well, compare [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca5db73e5d318e74) and [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ded4f8d0549034f4), instead of arguing with me

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Why does Lhs::normal work on rvalues and not on lvalues tho? I have no clue.

Comment: @Phantom because a forwarding reference becomes an lvalue reference for lvalues, so, e.g. `A&::normal` is never valid (see the ampersand)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I guess I missed that detail when learning about forwarding references.. For lvalues, T becomes T&, and the parameter becomes T& + && = T&&&, and collapses into T&. While for Rvalues, T is still T, and T + && = T&&. Right...? xD

Comment: @Phantom yes, and additionally, if someone explicitly specifies `T` in a template argument list as `T&&` (e.g. `modifyNormal<A&&>`) then once again, T&& + && collapses into T&&

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why do we need an extra type (`special_`/`general_`) in this method

These are used only for the purpose of allowing the `modifyNormal` function to be overloaded with different implementations. What is *special* about them is that `special_` uses the IS-A relationship since it inherits from `general_`. Furthermore, the `transform` function always calls the `modifyNormal` overload which takes the `special_` type, see the next part.

> what does `typename int_<decltype(Lhs::normal)>::type = 0` help us do

This is a template argument with a default value. The default value is present so that the `transform` function doesn't have to specify it, which is important because the other `modifyNormal` function doesn't have this template parameter. Furthermore, this template parameter is only added to invoke SFINAE.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae

> When substituting the deduced type for the template parameter fails, the specialization is discarded from the overload set instead of causing a compile error.

So if a failure occurs the `modifyNormal` function taking the `special_` type is removed from the set of overloads to consider. This only leaves the `modifyNormal` function taking a `general_` type and since `special_` IS-A `general_` type everything still works.

If a substitution failure does not occur then the `modifyNormal` function using the `special_` type will be used since it's a better match.

---

**Note:** The `general_` type is a `struct` so the inheritance is `public` by default, allowing the IS-A relationship without using the `public` keyword.

---

**Edit:**

> Can you comment on why we use the elaborate `typename int_<decltype(Lhs::normal)>::type` mechanism in the first place?

As stated above this is used to trigger the SFINAE behavior. However, it's not very elaborate when you break it down. At it's heart it wants to instantiate a instance of the `int_` struct for some type `T` and it has a `type` data type defined:

```
int_<T>::type
```

Since this is being used in a template the `typename` keyword needs to be added, see [When is the “typename” keyword necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary).

```
typename int_<T>::type
```

Lastly, what is the actual type used to instantiate the `int_` struct? That's determined by `decltype(Lhs::normal)`, which reports the type for `Lhs::normal`. If type `Lhs` type has a `normal` data member then everything succeeds. However, if it doesn't then there is a substitution failure and the importance of this is explained above.

Comment: Can you comment on why we use the elaborate `typename int_<decltype(Lhs::normal)>::type` mechanism in the first place? Isn't there a simpler way to make it fail?

Comment: @Phonon I added some more information to try an clarify the details for you.

Answer (score 1):

`special_`/`general_` are types used to let the compiler distinguish in between the two methods `modifyNormal`. Note that the third argument is not used. The general implementation does nothing, but in special case it modifies the normal.
Also note that `special_` is derived from `general_`. That means that if the specialized version of `modifyNormal` is not defined (SFINAE) the general case applies; if the specialized version exists, then it will be chosen (it is more specific).

Now there is a switch in the definition of `modifyNormal`; if the type (first argument of the template) has no member named `normal` then the template fails (SFINAE and do not complain about it, this is the trick about SFINAE) and it will be the other definition of `modifyNormal` that will apply (the general case). If the type defines a member named `normal` then the third argument of the template can be resolved to an additional third argument template (an `int` defaulted equals to 0). This third argument has no purpose to the function, only for SFINAE (the pattern applies on it).

Answer (score 1):

The types `general` and `special` are used to force the compiler to choose the first function (that is a better match) as a first try while trying to resolve the call.
Note that the call is:

```
modifyNormal(vertex, m, special_());
```

Anyway, because `general` inherits from `special`, both are valid and the second one will be chosen if the first fails during type substitution.

So, it's like to say - *let's have a go as if that method actually exists, but keep calm because we have a catch-all callback that does nothing*.

Why could it fail?
That's where `int_` takes its part in the game.
If the `decltype` (let me say) *gives an error* because the member method `normal` is missed in `Lhs`, `int_` cannot be specialized and the substitution actually fails, but thanks to SFINAE, this failure is not an error as long as there exists another substitution that can be tried (and it exists in our case, the method having `general` as an argument, that still is a less precise match for the original call).