# Modified code from "check if member exists using enable_if" is not working

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I read this article.
[check if member exists using enable_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786888/check-if-member-exists-using-enable-if)
I modified the code of Johanness Schaub like this.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct NormalChecker {
    struct general_ {};
    struct special_ : general_ {};
    template<typename> struct int_ { typedef int type; };

    template<typename Lhs>
    void modify(Lhs &&lhs) {
        cout << "modify\r\n";
        modifyNormal(lhs, special_());
    }

    template<typename Lhs, typename int_<decltype(Lhs::normal)>::type = 0>
    void modifyNormal(Lhs &&lhs, special_) {
        cout << "modifyNormal with normal\r\n";
    }

    template<typename Lhs>
    void modifyNormal(Lhs &&lhs, general_) {
        cout << "modifyNormal without normal\r\n";
    }
};

struct DataWithNormal {
    int normal;
};

struct DataWithoutNormal {
};

int main() {
    DataWithNormal with_normal;
    DataWithoutNormal without_normal;

    NormalChecker normalCheckerWithNormal;
    normalCheckerWithNormal.modify(with_normal);
    NormalChecker normalCheckerWithoutNormal;
    normalCheckerWithoutNormal.modify(without_normal);

    return 0;
}
```

But, it just says "modifyNormal without normal" twice.
What am I missed?

Comment: You are using non-standard-compliant compiler, probably pre-2017 Visual C++. Your code does not compile with "good" compilers.

Comment: I tested it at Visual C++ 2017, and no compile error happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Lhs` is deduced to be a reference type in your example, specifically `DataWithNormal&`. Reference types don't have a nested `normal`. One way to get around this is to check `Lhs` when references are stripped:

```
decltype(std::remove_reference<Lhs>::type::normal)
```

Lifting Igor's comment, you can also pretend you have an object, since accessing a member of an object works even with a reference:

```
decltype(std::declval<Lhs>().normal)
```

Comment: Perhaps a bit more natural: `decltype(std::declval<Lhs>().normal)`

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015,
template<typename Lhs, typename int_<decltype(std::remove_reference<Lhs>:type::normal)>::type = 0> doesn't work, but
template<typename Lhs, typename int_<decltype(std::declval<Lhs>().normal)>::type = 0> works.
Thanks.

Comment: @P-P, Oh, that's interesting. I tested it on both Clang and GCC. I figure when they both agree on something, it's usually correct. Unfortunately, I just noticed a little typo: `:type` instead of `::type`. I fixed that.